# Using one graph I want to see browser usage per browser over time in GA

Tags: google-analytics

When I view the Browser graph in Google Analytics I'm shown the total number of visits over time in the graph. Below I see the aggregate breakdown of browsers over the entire period.

What I want to see is browser usage over time for all (or some) of the browsers.

I can of course drill down into individual browsers (and further into versions) but this only shows me the usage of one browser at a time. How can I put all this information into one graph without exporting the data piece by piece and putting it in Excel?

It seems like a really simple view of data that anyone would want so I'm surprised it's not available in GA (or obvious for that matter).

Comment: Great question, I have wondered that myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use advanced segments to do this for up to four browsers.

Here's the first page of help for advanced segments:
https://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en-GB&answer=1033017&topic=1032940&rd=1

Create a segment for each browser and then use the advanced segments option on the graph to display those segments on it.